# Should I use exceptions in C# to enforce base class compatibility?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, exception

On one hand, I'm told that exceptions in C# are 'expensive', but on the other, I'm stuck on how to implement this.

My problem is this: I'm making a `Stream` derivitive, that wraps a `NetworkStream`. Now, the problem I'm facing is this: `Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)`. From the `Stream` docs for the function:

> Returns:
>
> ... or zero (0) if the end of the stream has been reached.

The problem is, in the protocol I'm implementing the remote side can send an "end of record" token, or a "please respond" token. Obviously, if this happens at the start of the `Read()` this causes problems, since I need to return from the function, and I havn't read anything, so I need to return 0, which means the stream is finished, but it isn't... is a `EndOfRecordException` or similar justified in this case? And in this case, should it aways be thrown when this token is encountered (at the start of the `Read()` call and make sure these tokens are always at the start by returning early) so that there is some sort of pattern to how these tokens should be handled.

**Edit:** For what it's worth, these tokens generally come through 3-10 times a second. At the most, I wouldn't expect more than 25 a second.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Exceptions aren't really all that expensive - but they also aren't necessarily the best way to manage expected/normal flow.

To me, it sounds like you aren't actually *implementing* a `Stream` - you are *encapsulating* a stream into a "reader". I might be inclined to write a protocol-specific reader class with suitable methods to detect the end of a record, or `Try...` methods to get data or return false.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you shouldn't really be deriving from `Stream` if your class is concerned with records. Streams don't generally *interpret* their data at all - they're just a transport mechanism of data from one place to another.

There have been cases like `ZipInputStream` in Java which end up being very confusing when a single `InputStream` effectively has several streams within it, and you can skip between them. Such APIs have been awful to use in my experience. Providing a separate class to implement the "record splitting" which can provide a stream for the data *within* a record sounds cleaner to me. Then each stream can behave consistently with normal streams. No need for new exceptions.

However, I'm just guessing at your context based on the limited information available. If you could give more details of the bigger picture, that would help.

Answer (score 1):

It's not such a big deal performance-wise, but still... Exceptions are intended for, well, exceptions. Situations that are "unusual". If that is the way the underlying stream behaves, then your stream should be able to handle it. If it can, it should handle it on its own. If not, you can have the user set some callback or something which will get called when you receive a "please respond" token.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that `Stream`-derived class should deal only with streaming issues and adhere to `Stream` semantic contract. All higher-level logic (interpreting EOF and EOR tokens) should be placed in some other class.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create an enum that you return, this enum can contain items for EndOfRecord, EndOfStream, ReadOk or whatever you need.

The actual read data can be passed as an out parameter.

Comment: Can't change the functions signature because it's defined in the base Stream class.